# OpenACC data movement

Tags: pragma, openacc

I am very new to OpenACC and I don't quite understand about the data movement and the "#pragma acc data" clause.

I have a program written in C. An extract from the code is like that:

```
#pragma acc data create(intersectionSet[0:intersectionsCount][0:4]) // line 122
#pragma acc kernels // line 123
for (int i = 0; i<intersectionsCount; i++){ // line 124
    intersectionSet[i][0] = 9; // line 125
}
```

intersectionsCount has value 210395. After compiling and run the above code by the following:

```
pgcc -o rect_openacc -fast -Minfo -acc -ta=nvidia,time rect.c
```

I have this output:

```
    time(us): 1,475,607
122: data region reached 1 time
    31: kernel launched 210395 times
        grid: [1]  block: [128]
         device time(us): total=1,475,315 max=15 min=7 avg=7
        elapsed time(us): total=5,451,647 max=24,028 min=24 avg=25
123: compute region reached 1 time
    124: kernel launched 1 time
        grid: [1644]  block: [128]
         device time(us): total=292 max=292 min=292 avg=292
        elapsed time(us): total=312 max=312 min=312 avg=312
156: data region reached 1 time
```

I have some questions after reading the output:

1. I don't know why it said line 31, as line 31 has no acc pragma. Does it mean something that I can't trace?
2. In the line "31: kernel launched 210395 times", it said it launched 210395 times the kernel. I don't know if it is normal that the kernel needs to launch so many times, because this part has taken 5,451,647(us) and I think it is a little bit long. I think the for-loop is simple and shouldn't take so much time. Am I using the pragma in a wrong way?

**Update**
I do have a couple of header files for the program. But those files do not have "acc data" or "acc kernels" pragma.

After compiling the code with "-Minfo=all", the result is as follows:

```
breakStringToCharArray:
 11, include "stringHelper.h"
      50, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
countChar:
 11, include "stringHelper.h"
      74, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: not countable
extractCharToIntRequiredInt:
 11, include "stringHelper.h"
      93, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
extractArray:
 12, include "fileHelper.h"
      49, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
isRectOverlap:
 13, include "shapeHelper.h"
      23, Generating acc routine vector
          Generating Tesla code
getRectIntersection:
 13, include "shapeHelper.h"
      45, Generating acc routine vector
          Generating Tesla code
getRectIntersectionInGPU:
 13, include "shapeHelper.h"
      69, Generating acc routine vector
          Generating Tesla code
max:
 13, include "shapeHelper.h"
      98, Generating acc routine vector
          Generating Tesla code
min:
 13, include "shapeHelper.h"
     118, Generating acc routine vector
          Generating Tesla code
main:
64, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
108, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
122, Generating create(intersectionSet[:intersectionsCount][:4])
124, Loop is parallelizable
     Accelerator kernel generated
     Generating Tesla code
124, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
```

I create intersectionSet in this way:

```
intersectionSet = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int **) * intersectionsCount);
for (i = 0; i<intersectionsCount; i++){
    intersectionSet[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);
}
```

Comment: 1. Hmm, that's a bit strange. Do you have any code being pulled in from a header file?
2. It looks like the compiler generated a kernel with 1 gang of 128 threads, so it's probably launching that kernel lots of times. Can you please post the compilation output with -Minfo=all? I bet it's not parallelizing what you think it should.

Comment: @jefflarkin I have updated the post to show what output came out when "-Minfo=all" is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that since you have pointer to pointers array, "**", (at least I'm guessing that's what intersectionSet is) the compiler must first allocate the pointer to pointer on the device, then loop over each element to allocate the individual device arrays.  Finally, it then needs to launch a kernel to set the pointer value on the device.  Here's some Pseudo-code to help illustrate.

```
devPtrPtr = deviceMalloc(numElements*pointer size);
for (i=0; i < numElements; ++i) {
   devPtr = deviceMalloc(elementSize * dataTypeSize);
   call deviceKernelToSetPointer<<<1,128>>(devPtrPtr[i],devPtr);
}
```

To help your code, I'd switch the dimensions making the column length 4 and the row length "intersectionsCount".  This will also help the data access on the device since the "vector" loop should correspond to the stride-1 (contiguous) dimension in order to avoid memory divergence.

Hope this helps,

Mat

Comment: I have my intersectionSet created in the way you mentioned (column=4, row=intersectionsCount. Please see my update for the initialization). Anything else I can try? thx

Comment: Your update shows columns=intersectionsCount and row=4.

Comment: Try inverting those.  Allocate intersectionSet with a size of 4 and then each element is sized to the intersectionsCount.  Then of course, the rest of your code needs to be updated as well.  Basically what you do when you create intersetionSet is the same thing the compiler needs to do when it's being created on the device, with the addition of launching a kernel to set the device pointer value in the pointer array.  Though with the column length set to 4, it only needs to launch 4 kernels instead of 210,395.

Comment: Thanks Mat, switching the dimension does improve the speed! I then further investigated the code and found that if I declare the array like this: int intersectionSet[intersectionsCount][4]; it also improved the speed. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I mean if I simply declare the array by the way above, not by malloc, the kernel only launched once

Comment: Because this is allocated as a single contiguous block of memory.  Hence, the compiler doesn't need to perform the pointer filling on the GPU as it does when using pointers to pointers.

Comment: so can I say it is no good to use malloc to allocate memory when using OpenACC?

Comment: No, it's fine but there is some extra overhead in order to fill the pointers on the device. You just happen to have an extreme case.